# Execute PS from bat for Intune Win32

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, intune

I am so confused and actually also not so familiar with PS and bat after my troubles with them.

I want to set the Lockscreen in Windows 10 with Intune through an IntuneWin file (WIN32 application).

I have a folder with the image, which I want to set, a copy.bat which should copy the image in the directory and also execute the PS file for setting the login image and a del.bat for deleting the image.

**copy.bat**

```
md %AllUsersProfile%\sz
copy /Y Wallpaper.jpg %AllUsersProfile%\sz
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Set-Lockscreen.ps1 -verb RunAs
```

**del.bat**

```
del /Y %AllUsersProfile%\sz\Wallpaper.jpg
```

**Set-Lockscreen.ps1**

```
$RegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationLS"
$LockScreenPath = "LockScreenImagePath"
$LockScreenStatus = "LockScreenImageStatus"
$LockScreenUrl = "LockScreenImageUrl"
$StatusValue = "1" 

$path = "C:\ProgramData\Elinvar"
$LockScreenImageValue = "C:\ProgramData\sz\Wallpaper.jpg"

 sIf ((Test-Path -Path $path) -eq $false)
{
 New-Item -Path $path -ItemType directory
}
 
if (!(Test-Path $RegKeyPath))
{
 Write-Host "Creating registry path $($RegKeyPath)."
 New-Item -Path $RegKeyPath -Force | Out-Null
}
 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenStatus -Value $StatusValue -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenPath -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name $LockScreenUrl -Value $LockScreenImageValue -PropertyType STRING -Force | Out-Null
 
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
```

I pack all these files with [Microsoft Win32 Content Prep Tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft-Win32-Content-Prep-Tool) and upload this in Intune as Win32 file.
Upload works, assigning to a group works, installation is successful. All good so far, I thought.

If I check the directory, the image is in %AllUsersProfile%\sz.
But when I check the reg, the entry is not set.

When I run the copy.bat file manually, It doesn't work. Only when I run it as administrator.
When I run the last line in cmd as administrator, so

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Set-Lockscreen.ps1 -verb RunAs
```

It works as well.

I think Intune is not running the script as administrator.
In Intune there is no configuration to say, run this command as administrator.
Maybe with a syntax? Does anyone know this?
Something like

```
copy.bat RunAs
```

I also export the reg file and import this with

```
reg import PersonalizationLS.reg
```

It didn't work.

I think there must be a way to execute the installation command in intune to run the script as admin.
It needs just for the last line the administrator privilege , md and copy work without administrator privileges. (same also for important reg file).

Comment: As an aside: Just like you use `%AllUsersProfile%` in your batch files to refer to the all-users data directory, you should use `$env:AllUsersProfile` in your PowerShell script.

Comment: Why use batch files at all?

Comment: pretty easy to manage. and it is not related to the batch file, it is more how the file will be execute. In intune u have just one field for installation command. and I just type copy.bat. sure I could also Use PowerShell, but when it is not possible to run powershell from this section in intune with admin privilegs, it won't  help.

For now, I transfered the file with IntuneWinAppUtil and executed the PS through the script section to set the registry. Not the best way, but it works.

Comment: I did in my post. transferring file with IntuneWinAppUtil and execute the script via intune script setting for setting the registry.